# Trying to run multiple commands in a dockerfile with different js files in different directories

Tags: node.js, docker

got a question with regards to running multiple docker commands in my Dockerfile. My current directory structure looks like this (with the addition of 3 different `node_modules` taken out cause...they're long.

```
.
├── bot
│   ├── bot.js
│   ├── firebase-cred.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── README.md
│   └── yarn.lock
├── docker-compose.yml
├── dockerfile
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── proxy-server
│   ├── main.js
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   └── README.md
└── README.md
```

I want to be able to run `bot.js` and `main.js` in that order. How do I run a command like that?

```
FROM node:17-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
CMD ["npm", ""]
```

I'd also like to know how this would work with my, currently empty, `docker-compose` since I'd like to run the docker-compose and have the app run.

Comment: When do you want to run them; as part of the image build or as the main process in a container?  Does `bot.js` exit or is it a long-running service?  Why does the ordering matter?